# Problem saving pdf with wkhmltopdf - Cakephp 3

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm using [CakePdf](https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/CakePdf)

The documentation gives this example to create inside a folder:

```
<?php
    $CakePdf = new \CakePdf\Pdf\CakePdf();
    $CakePdf->template('newsletter', 'default');
    $CakePdf->viewVars($this->viewVars);
    $CakePdf->write(APP . 'files' . DS . 'newsletter.pdf');
```

I replaced by:

```
$CakePdf->write("/webroot/img/" . 'newsletter.pdf');
```

However, the file is not created. I am grateful if someone can analyze me or indicate a way to implement this!

Comment: `/webroot` seems like a folder that doesn't really exist. Do you mean something like `/usr/edrian/cake/webroot`?

Comment: I needed to use WWW_ROOT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always use **[DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR](http://xhttps://www.php.net/manual/en/dir.constants.php)** or **[DS](https://github.com/cakephp/app/blob/726484547dcbdb95e22c0e39f1105f7c1347c867/config/paths.php#L18)** in CakePHP applications.

But in this case you need to use the predefined constan **[WWW_ROOT](https://github.com/cakephp/app/blob/master/config/paths.php#L56)** to build the correct path in the backend of the application.

```
$CakePdf->write(WWW_ROOT . 'img' . DS . 'newsletter.pdf');
```

In templates create link to file like

```
<a href="/img/newsletter.pdf">News Leter</a>
```